# Dynamically render ACF fields from wordpress rest api in react

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

I'm trying to dynamically map out the response that i get from the wordpress rest api. The problem I'm having is that the response im getting looks like this:

```
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 18, date: "2018-05-02T14:31:37", date_gmt: "2018-05-02T14:31:37", guid: {…}, modified: "2018-05-02T14:51:14", …}
1
:
{id: 17, date: "2018-05-02T14:31:18", date_gmt: "2018-05-02T14:31:18", guid: {…}, modified: "2018-05-02T14:51:23", …}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Both these objects have another object inside them called acf that includes my fields that i want to render out.

This is how i want to render the fields:

```
const dateData = [
{
  date: '18-04-23',
  time: '9pm',
  title: 'MGM Grand Garden Arena',
},
{
  date: '18-04-23',
  time: '9pm',
  title: 'MGM Grand Garden Arena',
},
{
  date: '18-04-23',
  time: '9pm',
  title: 'MGM Grand Garden Arena',
},
]

  const dateRender = dateData.map((t, i) => (
    <div key={i} className="date-item">
      <p>{t.date}</p>
      <p>{t.time}</p>
      <p>{t.title}</p>
    </div>
  ));
```

But it's not working because the acf fields is nested inside two different objects. The purpose of this is that the user should be able to add new dates in wordpress dashboard and it should render it out dynamically. Any tips?

Thanks!